# how to use just kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I'm try to decrease page size to less than 300 KB and i want to use and load just require 'kendo javascript' file , except 'kendo.web.min.js'
According to [This document](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies) i wrote code below but this did not work :( please help me

```
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.core.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.data.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.grid.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var products = [{
            ProductID: 1,
            ProductName: "Chai",
            SupplierID: 1,
            CategoryID: 1,
            QuantityPerUnit: "10 boxes x 20 bags",
            UnitPrice: 18.0000,
            UnitsInStock: 39,
            UnitsOnOrder: 0,
            ReorderLevel: 10,
            Discontinued: false,
            Category: {
                CategoryID: 1,
                CategoryName: "Beverages",
                Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
            }
        }, {
            ProductID: 2,
            ProductName: "Chang",
            SupplierID: 1,
            CategoryID: 1,
            QuantityPerUnit: "24 - 12 oz bottles",
            UnitPrice: 19.0000,
            UnitsInStock: 17,
            UnitsOnOrder: 40,
            ReorderLevel: 25,
            Discontinued: false,
            Category: {
                CategoryID: 1,
                CategoryName: "Beverages",
                Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
            }
        }, {
            ProductID: 3,
            ProductName: "Aniseed Syrup",
            SupplierID: 1,
            CategoryID: 2,
            QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 550 ml bottles",
            UnitPrice: 10.0000,
            UnitsInStock: 13,
            UnitsOnOrder: 70,
            ReorderLevel: 25,
            Discontinued: false,
            Category: {
                CategoryID: 2,
                CategoryName: "Condiments",
                Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
            }
        }, {
            ProductID: 4,
            ProductName: "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
            SupplierID: 2,
            CategoryID: 2,
            QuantityPerUnit: "48 - 6 oz jars",
            UnitPrice: 22.0000,
            UnitsInStock: 53,
            UnitsOnOrder: 0,
            ReorderLevel: 0,
            Discontinued: false,
            Category: {
                CategoryID: 2,
                CategoryName: "Condiments",
                Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
            }
        }];

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: products,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            ProductName: { type: "string" },
                            UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                            Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 20
            },
            height: 550,
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false
            },
            columns: [
                "ProductName",
                { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Did you get a javascript error? Or did your grid now get created?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: My problem is the grid dose not create,I use the jquery that was in the kendo package

Comment: Can you open the jquery file and check the version. Kendo ui 2012.3 needs a certain version of jquery

Comment: Kendo UI 2012.3.1114 (Q3 2012) - jQuery 1.8.2
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#jquery-version

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer : my problem solved by adding reference of kendo.pager.min.js file